# Can't load angular generated webpage (ng build --prod)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular8, webdeploy

After deploying my angular app by using '**ng build --prod**' I tried to open index.html file and check my webapp. But it display nothing in chrome, firefox and edge web browsers. After I open console and checked whether is there are any errors, it will show me 6 error messages.

[image: 6 errors in my webapp]

**I should mention that my app successfully compiled and worked on** '**http://localhost:4200/**' .
After I tried another angular app(new one), but it comes withe same kind of errors after build.

Errors:

1) Access to script at 'file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

2) GET file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js net::ERR_FAILED

3) Access to script at 'file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
index.html:36

4) GET file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js net::ERR_FAILED
index.html:1

5) Access to script at 'file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/main-es2015.69da1b25d5a7a648b825.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
index.html:36

6) GET file:///D:/AngularTshirt/module01/moduleapp01/dist/moduleapp01/main-es2015.69da1b25d5a7a648b825.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: there is no problem. If you are using the VS Code the use live server

Comment: read more about CORS to get better understanding about the policy

Comment: You need to _serve_ the app. Which is exactly what the built-in _server_ does on localhost:4200. Opening the HTML file alone won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to run the application without a server serving the js bundles generated by Angular.  Angular will load the js asynchronously.

An option run `live-server` on the compiled directory

```
// Install live-server if you haven't
npm install -g live-server

// Run live-server on you dist
cd <project-compile-dist-path>
live-server

// Note: if you don't want to install live-server globally you
// can use npx
npx live-server <path-to-directory>
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve your project's `dist/moduleapp01` folder from a HTTP server. The browser automatically blocks some requests when they are made from your file system due to security reasons (what you tried to do). You can use `http-server` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

From your project's root you can start the server with `http-server ./dist/moduleapp01 -p 4200` and open it in the browser at `http://localhost:4200`.