# How to run a built Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular9

I finish developing my Angular app, and I execute:

```
ng build
```

It successfully passed and a new directory `dist/` was generated, but I didn't find out how to run it locally before searching how to host it.

Comment: You can use and npm package called live-server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878123/cant-load-angular-generated-webpage-ng-build-prod/58878286#58878286

Comment: What is you system?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16, I want to run it locally, then host it, I thought that I will have a simple project as a page html liniking some javascript and css files as output of ng build but what I'm going to do now ?!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a server either using NodeJS or using spring boot that will serve this Angular app from the `dist/` folder

Comment: either on hosting, NodeJs is required ?

Comment: @MedKarimGarali the easiest thing that you can do is, that you can deploy your Angular application on Heroku. The free tier version of Heroku lets you host upto 5 applications at a time. For this you would only need to, setup automatic deployment pipeline once you login to Heroku dashboard and connect it to to your github repo. Here is a medium article that you can follow in order to achieve this
https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147